# Qt and OpenSSL incompatible version on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, openssl

I am having issues trying to make QNetwork classes work with Qt5.11.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

I have openssl 1.1.0g and libssl-dev installed on my system.

The openssl version used by Qt is 1.0.2k. I have checked with `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()`. Plus `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` returns `false`.

I am trying to get my head around this but I am always having these errors:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ERR_free_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_new_null
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_push
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_ex_new_index
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL
```

I have checked multiple questions and forums about that and nothing seems to work for me. Anybody got any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have finally managed to make it work.

I have installed openssl 1.0.2k from the sources. I have downloaded the version I needed [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.2/) and followed the tutorial on [this page](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/).

After doing so I was still having some of the errors but not the ones for the incompatible version. To fix that I have installed `libssl1.0-dev` and everything was good to go (thx to [this guy](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001#issuecomment-309673453)).

I hope this will help somebody.

Comment: Musescore had me in a login loop until i launched it from the terminal, this error showed up and i found your answer. Thanks dude!!

Comment: Thank you, I downgraded OpenSSL via apt from 1.1 to 1.0 and my issues vanished.

Answer (score 4):

I've copied `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` (v1.0.2) to my current compiler lib directory (`<QTDIR>/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib`). 
In my case I took theese 2 libs in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`: `libssl.so.1.0.0` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`, copied and renamed.
It worked for me.

Comment: avoid copying libraries around, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is your best friend for this to be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

using the maintenance tool you can add openSSL-1.1.1

you can find it at`<QT-INSTALLATION-DIR>/tools/openSSL/src`

then build it

```
$ ./config --prefix=$HOME/openssl-1.1.1/ssl --openssldir=$HOME/openssl-1.1.1/ssl shared zlib
$ make
$ make install
```

and based on @vvas [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319722/14745345) copy `libcrypto.so.1.1` `libssl.so.1.1` to `<QTDIR>/6.3.1/gcc_64/lib`

this has worked for me ... with Qt 6.3.1 on fedora 36

Comment: Timely. This just worked on ubuntu 22.04 && qt 6.2.4

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem creating a symobolic link to openssl 1.1.0, this way:

Create symbolic links that overwrite libcrypto.so.1.0.0 and libssl.so.1.0.0 in /opt/f5/vpn/lib:

```
    sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 /opt/f5/vpn/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 

    sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /opt/f5/vpn/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: had the same issue with f5vpn and those commands saved me and solved the problem of openssl / libssl but still facing QT version issue, requesting 5.5 and i have 5.12, i don't know why they are considering 5.12 < 5.5 loool, @Guilherme did you get this error too?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Qt 5.13.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Values of `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()` and `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` in my Qt environment are `"OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019"` and `false`.

This output was generated every time `QNetworkAccessManager` accessed an https address:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_init_ssl
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_init_crypto
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ASN1_STRING_get0_data
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve RSA_bits
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_new_null
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_push
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_num
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_pop_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_value
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve DH_get0_pqg
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_options
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_psk_use_session_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_client_random
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_SESSION_get_master_key
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_session_reused
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_options
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLS_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLS_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLS_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_up_ref
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_getm_notBefore
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_getm_notAfter
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_get_version
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_set_ex_data
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_get_ex_data
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OpenSSL_version_num
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OpenSSL_version
qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed
```

Non of above solutions worked for me. I installed [Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux#install) package manager on my Ubuntu and then installed [openssl@1.1](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/blob/df914d4b835e71799551b76b85dd4296c0480310/Formula/openssl%401.1.rb) like this:

```
$ brew install openssl@1.1
```

Then I just added these lines to my project file:

```
LIBS += -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1c/lib -lssl -lcrypto
INCLUDEPATH += /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1c/include
```

The value of `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()` remained the old value `"OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019"` but the value of `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` became `true` and it solved my problem.